# iOS App - How to set app's default document storage lcation to "on My Device" by code?

Tags: ios, storage, document, icloud

I'm developing a document based iOS app and would like to set this app's document storage location to "on My Device (iPhone/iPad)" by source code.

I noticed that once my app is installed on an iOS device, the document storage location is always set to "iCloud Drive", therefore users need to manually change it to "on My Device" in the iOS settings app if they do not want to use iCloud drive.
[image]

Is there an iOS API or plist property to tell the system that this app prefers storing documents on the device instead of on iCloud Drive?
Thanks for any suggestions.